# System Management is locked by ... packagekitd

Tags: linux, opensuse, opensuse-11.2

I've installed OpenSUSE 11.2 x86 in a VM (VMWare Workstation 7). Whenever I try to add/configure apps (fresh from a reboot), I get:

> System management is locked by the application with pid 3276 (/usr/sbin/packagekitd).

I've tried waiting etc; no joy.

I'm not very linux-savvy, and searches haven't yielded much of use. What can I do to get this working? i.e. so that I can add / configure packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the updater applett or something like that. On a console:

> sudo kill 3276

Comment: Seems to work; not quite sure what I've killed, but... ;-p

Answer (score 3):

`y2base` is YaST itself.

Close its window or use the `kill` command as admintech suggested.